# TypeError: Value does not implement interface WindowProxy

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to port an add-on from chrome to firefox. The add-on is going to be modern style (bootstrapped / SDK), and I'm using the Add-On Builder.

In a content script, I am trying to synthesize an event with the following code:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

I recieve an error on the call to `initMouseEvent`:

> TypeError: Value does not implement interface WindowProxy.

Looking at the variables:

```
console.log("element:", ""+element);
console.log("document:", ""+document);
console.log("window:", ""+thewindow);
```

They have strange wrappers, but are of the expected type underneath. Any ideas how I can get the call to succeed?

```
element: [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLDivElement]]
document: [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLDocument]]
window: [object XrayWrapper [object Window]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace `window` with `unsafeWindow`, and `document` with `unsafeWindow.document`.

I thought there are two kinds of scripts, the backend scripts that live in `lib`, and the content scripts that live in `data`. It turns out that while content scripts can modify your pages, they are not *actually* injected into the page. It's not as if you just hung your script beneath the page's source. Insead, content scripts and page scripts live in slightly different contexts. `unsafeWindow` is the `window` from the actual page's script. I belive the reason for this is that a malicious page might manipulate the methods of it's `window`, and thus change the behaviour of your content script.

I don't know whether there is a way to emulate events without using `unsafeWindow` (the page might change `document.createEvent`, and what then?). It works in Chrome without `unsafeWindow`. If someone points out how to do this correctly, or elaborates on why it's OK to use `unsafeWindow`, I could accept that answer.